# Rake Aborted when doing a migration to a server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

Im trying to do a migration in my server but i get this code when i do rake db:migrate . I did it perfectly on my computer.

```
Please install the sqlite3 adapter: `gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter` (sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)
/home/magnet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:214:in `block in replace_gem'
/home/magnet/liga7/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/magnet/liga7/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/magnet/liga7/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/home/magnet/liga7/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/home/magnet/liga7/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/magnet/liga7/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:50:in `resolve_hash_connection'
/home/magnet/liga7/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:41:in `resolve_string_connection'
/home/magnet/liga7/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:25:in `spec'
/home/magnet/liga7/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:130:in `establish_connection'
/home/magnet/liga7/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/home/magnet/liga7/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
/home/magnet/liga7/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
/home/magnet/liga7/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:in `block in on_load'
/home/magnet/liga7/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `each'
/home/magnet/liga7/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
```

.....

Does someone know what to do ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Do you have a `sqlite3` gem installed on the server?

Comment: I think so. I was doing some changes (adding a column to a table) only so i think that it is. (im starting in ruby)

Comment: Do you really want to use `sqlite3` in production server?

Comment: I was using it before and has been working perfect. Why shouldnt i use it ?

Comment: Are you running it on production? Have you specified the environment? `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better you could you `gem pg`,because it will support all database adapter,

Add in Gemfile

```
gem 'pg'
```

then

```
bundle install
```

then start migrate.

Comment: have you installed `sqlite3` ?

Comment: Thank youuu ! I fixed it using rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production rails c

Answer (score 0):

Add this to Gemfile

```
gem 'sqlite3'
```

And then

```
bundle install
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

And if it doesnot help then replace the line

```
gem 'sqlite3'
```

with

```
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.9'
```

and run the above commands.
And if it doesnot help then install sqlite on your system if it is not installed and repeat the above process.